# Interactive IK Rig

Tags: animation, three.js, webgl

I'm wondering if anybody has seen an interactive IK rig in three.js. I've seen a number of examples that show the ability to manipulate individual bones in a rig, but this doesn't seem all that useful.

What I'm imagining is a rigged model (let's say it's a model of a person) with the ability to click and drag on a body part (let's say a hand), and have the hand move with the arm bones following suit.

Actually, for that matter, is there any known way to load IK animations into a Three.js scene at all? I recently tried, but could only load an animation that had been baked from the IK to the bones in Maya.

Comment: No haven't seen that and it's not there out of the box. I looked into a few IK implementations a while ago with the idea of writing an implementation for three.js but didn't get to it then.

Comment: Hi, I also was looking for it but as of today there is still no working solution: you need to move each bone individually using rotations and it's quite tough.